# Trouble with performance using EF6 many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm seeing extreme slowness in production (anywhere from 30-120 seconds) when doing an INSERT using EF6 (6.0.1).  I have a many-to-many relationship between Device and Trigger.  Device has a virtual ICollection and Trigger has a virtual ICollection.  Trigger, for the most part is a static table (currently only one row).  When I need to create a new Device, I also need to create a mapping to the single Trigger row.  So I do a quick search for that row and do a device.Triggers.Add().  But that seems to be taking forever as EF6 drills down to functions like ObjectStateManager.UpdateRelationships and ObjectStateManager.TryUpdateExistingRelationships.  I'm assuming it's updating all of the devices under my Trigger instance.  How do I prevent this from happening?  Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks,
tim

**UPDATE:** Ok I found a possible workaround.  If I remove the Trigger-to-Device side of the relationship (i.e. delete the ICollection from Trigger) since I don't really need it and then set it up using the fluent method like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Triggers)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.MapLeftKey("Device_Id");
        x.MapRightKey("Trigger_Id");
        x.ToTable("TriggerDevices");
    });
```

But it seems like I shouldn't have to do this.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Tim, just repeating what I said in [Codeplex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/468551): we tried replicating the scenario you described here but we couldn't get anywhere the results you are reporting, so we would be grateful if you could provide a full repro.

Answer (score 0):

When database access takes that long it is usually due to a lock that is waiting for a timeout, rather than the database doing alot of work.

You could check:

- Database locks.
- User SQL Profiler to see which request you are sending to the database.
- Do you have "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" in your connection string, if this is missing it could explain the locks.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't believe my problem was any of those things.  I have "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" in my connection string.  And I looked at profiler and there were no long running queries or locks.  And I was able to reproduce it on my local box (running against my local SQL Server) with no other activity.  I used dotTrace to tell me that all the time was being spent in the functions I mentioned in my OP.  And it's probably obvious, but the times got worse as my Device table got larger (it currently has around 25k rows).

Answer (score 0):

Please accept that this is my first post - sorry for any etiquette errors.

I have just had the same problem in a production system; the solution was to reverse the addition.

For the sake of this example:-

Triggers has 1 row, Devices has 100,000 rows and the entity framework context object is called “db”

If you add a new device to triggers, using

```
    var trigger = db.Triggers.Single(t => t.ID == <triggerID> );
    trigger.devices.add(newDevice);
```

ef will load the entire collection of devices (you have a lot of devices joined to your one trigger) so that it can perform change tracking on the ICollection devices property of object trigger.

However if you use newDevice.Triggers.add(exitingTrigger) then ef won’t load any data from the source, change tracking knows newDevice is to be created, and the list only has one item in it anyway, even if ef did want to query the source.

Was I one of the few to miss this in the EF documentation?